# With ffmpeg's image to movie feature, is it possible to pass in frames over a period of time versus all at once?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

For the purpose of making a time lapse recording of desktop activity, it is possible so "stream" the frame list to ffmpeg over time, rather than all at once in the beginning.

Currently, it is a two step process.

1. save individual snapshots to disc

   im = ImageGrab.grab()
   im.save("frame_%s.jpg" % count, 'jpg')
2. compile those snapshots with ffmpeg via

   ffmpeg -r 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 out.mp4

It would be nice if there were a way to merge the two steps so that I'm not flooding my hard drive with thousands of individual snapshots. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg can grab the screen: [How to grab the desktop (screen) with FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20grab%20the%20desktop%20%28screen%29%20with%20FFmpeg)

In Linux you could do it with:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 1 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

(change video_size to your desktop size)